# PHP Unserialization and duplicate variable names

Tags: php, security, serialization

Recently I stumbled across [this](https://govolutionde.wordpress.com/2014/02/16/php-object-injection-in-contao-2-11-13/) description of a PHP Object Injection vulnerability in an older version of the CMS Contao (It's written in german but I will translate the crucial parts).

There the author says, he didn't manage to get Null-Bytes to the unserialize function (they were filtered out) so he wasn't directly able to write to protected or private members of a class.

Then he says this wouldn't be a problem, because **the unserialize() function wouldn't care if the serialized version of the class has public members that are actually protected in the real class** so he could just remove the leading Null-Bytes and the stars and correct the length of the variable name strings (just making the variables public in the serialized version) to get the attack to work (so **writing to the protected members  of a vulnerable class**).

Then I tried writing my own PoC of this behavior but failed.
First I created a little test class called 'Test' which has the protected member 'value' and a destructor which prints this value:

```
class Test {
   protected $value = "Default";

   public function __destruct() {
      echo $this->value . "<br>";
   }
}
```

Now I'm trying to change the value of the protected 'value' member.
With the Null-Bytes and the Star, everything works fine:

```
$obj = unserialize("O:4:\"Test\":1:{s:8:\"\0*\0value\";s:8:\"Injected\";}");
echo serialize($obj);
```

*gives me:*
O:4:"Test":1:{s:8:"*value";s:8:"Injected";}
Injected

Now I tried leaving out the Null-Bytes and the star so I pretended that 'value' would be a public variable:

```
$obj2 = unserialize("O:4:\"Test\":1:{s:5:\"value\";s:8:\"Injected\";}"); // I pretended that 'value' would be a public variable
echo serialize($obj2);
```

*This gives me:*
O:4:"Test":2:{s:8:"*value";s:7:"Default";s:5:"value";s:8:"Injected";}
Default

If you look at the serialized version of the class it seems like the PHP-Object has got two members with the **same name but a different visibility**. The destructor prints out the **protected member** so the **injection doesn't work**.

Now I'm wondering whether I'm missing something in this context or why this seemed to work for the author of the article. I would very appreciate your help here!

Comment: Could be PHP version related. Take a look into the changelogs about that.

Comment: The injection works since Version 7.2: https://3v4l.org/SaDri - See here how its exploitable and how to prevent: https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/PHP_Object_Injection

Comment: Well, it always worked, but since 7.2 its easier since you dont need the `\0*\0` anymore. - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a32989f23ffeb462f96959c2447547ecee137631